# Flex: Runtime Font Loading

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, font-face

I've tested this snippet with 3 different TTF fonts and I still din't get `@font-face` working within Flex. Am I missing something here?
Tried both absolute and relative paths on `url()`, no changes. If I use any standard font (Arial, Verdana, Tahoma...), the `Hello World!` text appears, but when I try to use any external font, nothing shows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="100%" height="100%">
 <mx:Style>
  @font-face {
      src: url(josefin-sans.ttf);
      fontFamily: JosefinSans;
  }

  .custom {
      fontFamily: JosefinSans;
      fontSize: 36pt;
  }
</mx:Style>
<mx:Text id="text" styleName="custom" text="Hello World!" />
```

Compiled with:

```
mxmlc -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true flex.mxml
```

Comment: Is the font file located in the root of your source folder?

Comment: @RIAstar The font file was located in the same folder of my .mxml. I solved the problem putting `embedAsCFF: false;` in the `@font-face` declaration. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using MX components, you should embed fonts with `embedAsCFF: false;` flag.

```
@font-face
{
    src: url("josefin-sans.ttf");
    fontFamily: "JosefinSans";
    fontWeight: normal;
    embedAsCFF: false;
}
```

If it doesn't work, launch the application in debug mode and watch for errors. Also, be sure that the font you are using can be displayed with bold and italic if needed.

Comment: Ermm, tried with `embedAsCFF: true;` and it doesn't worked. So I've searched for this flag and got that documentation page named "Troubleshooting fonts in applications": http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6320a-7fec.html
At the end it says to try with `embedAsCFF: false;`, and voilà, IT WORKED! Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: Well yes, "false" obviously, my fault :)